# Как правильно в CSS обратиться к элементам неупорядоченного списка?

Tags: css, list, ul

Есть блок (`.block`) с неупорядоченным списком внутри. Как правильно в `CSS` обратиться к элементам списка этого блока:

`.block ul li {…}` или `.block li {…}`?

И так, и так — всё действует. Но как же правильно и почему?

Comment: Теоретически так `.block li {…}` быстрее, тк меньше селекторов браузеру надо сравнивать. Не и меньше css получается. Практически удобнее более полное дерево использовать, наглядно понятней. И точно придется использовать полное дерево, если в этом списке будут вложенные списки.

Comment: Есть ещё предположение, что использование `.block ul li {…}` может быть обусловлено необходимостью отделить правила конкретно для неупорядоченного списка от упорядоченного, если такой есть (например, `.block ol li {…}`), а в конструкции `.block li {…}` мы обращаемся ко всем `li`, независимо от вида списка.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, не совсем понятно про необходимость использования полного дерева, если в списке будут вложенные списки. Например, если нужно обратиться к элементам списка внутри списка, то конструкция `.block li li {…}` и `.block ul li li {…}` действуют равнозначно. Или есть какие-то нюансы?

Comment: css читается "изнутри", то есть сначала ищется последний элемент вложенности (в нашем случае `li`), дальше ищутся родители, по этому чем меньше родителей - тем быстрее отрабатывает построение каскада. Что касается "правильности", то правильно и то и то (собственно этот вывод следует из того, что работает и так и так), в том числе более глубокая вложенность используется для переопределения стилей для отдельных элементов подмножеств каскада.

Comment: Если внутри списка есть ещё один список, то `.block ul li` и `.block li` подействуют на оба списка, а `.block > ul > li` только на один внешний (а про остальное уже рассказали выше в комментах)

Comment: По вложенности как раз имелл виду то, о чем написал @andreymal. А если использовать препроцессоры, то визуально получается тоже дерево, что и в html, что делает весь код понятней.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ваш комментарий, на мой взгляд, больше остальных дан по сути (и тем самым помог мне разобраться в вопросе). Оформите его как ответ.

Comment: @eav, добавил ответ, внизу ссылка на хабру, можете ознакомиться более подробно со всем этим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильным будет и так и так, главный вопрос: Что быстрее?

**1)** CSS читается справа налево, то есть в селекторе `.block ul li` сначала будут найдены все `li` на странице, дальше отсеются все `li` которые не вложены в `ul`, затем из оставшихся отсеются те которые не вложены в `.block`. Следовательно:

**=> Чем меньше вложенность, тем быстрее**

**2)** Разные селекторы имеют разную скорость обработки. Скорость от наибольшей к наименьшей:

> - Идентификатор: #id
> - Класс: .class
> - Элемент: div
> - Соседний элемент: h2 + p
> - Дочерний элемент: ul > li
> - Вложенный элемент: ul li
> - Общий селектор: *
> - Атрибут: [type=«email»]
> - Псевдоклассы/псевдоэлементы: a:hover/a::before

**=> Лучше всего использовать идентификаторы или классы (скорость разнится незначительно). В остальном надо ориентироваться на этот список**

Собственно на этих принципах и строится основная идеология BEM - минимум вложенности, все стили задаются через классы.

Информация взята с [хабры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/244815/).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так: .block ul > li{.......}

Comment: ключевой вопрос всего этого вопроса "почему?" Попытайтесь дать более развернутый ответ.